# Rails authorization? check in Model vs controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I am doing a check on a `user` model to determine whether s/he has one or more `task_list`, if she has more than one task_list only then she is allowed to delete it, otherwise an exception is thrown. I basically have an method called delete_list in the user model to allow for short hand deletions such as `user1.delete_list(list1)`

I am debating whether to put the check in CanCan where it would be apply as a before filter on the controller or whether to have it in the user model as well . What is the recommended practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good DRY approach to this would be to create a method in your model that tests whether a delete is allowed. Then use that method from your controller or from ability.rb. IMHO I think having complicated permission/business logic decoupled from CanCan is better when there is a chance you might change to a different permission system in the future.

In your model:

```
def can_destroy_list(list)
   ... Do check here ....
end
```

In ability.rb

```
can :destroy, List do |list|  
    user.can_destroy_list(list)
end
```

Your controller and views can then also use `can_destroy_list` directly on the model instance if nessary or use: if `can? :destroy, @list`